# Rename sequential files to a row/column format

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of files numbered from 1 to 128.

```
image-1
image-2
...
image-10
...
image-99
...
image-128
```

How do I rename them using the Windows command line to row/column format with letters a to h and numbers 1 to 16, like a spreadsheet.

```
image-a01
image-a02
...
image-a10
...
image-g03
...
image-h16
```

And so on. Thanks.

For the letter refer to this table.

```
a = 1-16
b = 17-32
c = 33-48
d = 49-64
e = 65-80
f = 81-96
g = 97-112
h = 113-128
```

The number after the letter is simply the modulo of the input number and 16. For instance `MOD(num, 16)`, except that the 0 should be a 16.

Comment: What is the mapping function between the current file names and the new one?  Is there data in the file that can be used to determine what the new name should be? Please [edit] your post to include additional information.

Comment: They are bitmap images that have no text in them.

Comment: Your question as it stands now, cannot be answered.  How are we to determine that `image-10` should be renamed `image-a10`?  What rules define the transformation?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is the explanation better?

Comment: Yes.  I retract my vote to close.  "MOD(num, 16), except that the 0 should be a 16" is a very important detail btw.  I requires additional increment and modulus operations.  I recommend that you try `help for`, `help set` and `help setlocal`. Think about what you are trying accomplish, write some code, if you fail, read [mcve] and then post questions for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think I will be using a batch file again in the future. I can't read that code. Python is much more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just posted a code request with no further effort to explain the problem...

Well, here it is the code you requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "b=abcdefgh" & set "c=0"
for /L %%b in (1,1,128) do (
   set /A "d=(a=%%b%%16)+16*^!a+100"
   for %%c in (!c!) do echo ren image-%%b image-!b:~%%c,1!!d:~1!
   set /A "c+=^!a"
)
```

**EDIT**: I added parts of the output of last code:

```
ren image-1 image-a01
ren image-2 image-a02
- - -
ren image-15 image-a15
ren image-16 image-a16
ren image-17 image-b01
ren image-18 image-b02
- - -
ren image-31 image-b15
ren image-32 image-b16
ren image-33 image-c01
ren image-34 image-c02
- - -
- - -
ren image-127 image-h15
ren image-128 image-h16
```

Comment: We're not here to provide a coding service.  If your answer included some explanation of exactly what function it implements, and; since the OP seems to be a batch-file newb, some explanations/references to help them understand why you wrote the solution in that particular form, I might be persuaded to give you an up-vote.

Comment: @jwdonahue: My obfuscated code was written with the purpose that the OP realizes that the problem description lacks a ton of details... If the OP give us more explanations _and ask for further explanations of my code_, then I gladly will give that. The OP should learn that if he/she wants clearer answers, then he/she must post clearer questions.  **`;)`**  On the other hand, my code do exactly what the OP wants; see the output example I added. I wrote it just for fun...

Comment: I agree with some of your points, but I would also point out that the OP is just an ever decreasing fraction of the population of readers of this thread.  Do the rest of us a favor, and don't be spiteful with your answers.